# Two monitors as two X screens on Fedora using nvidia drivers?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

In NVIDIA X Server Settings on X Server Display Configuration I have an option to have two monitors on using separate X screens. But the program want to save this setting to Xorg.conf, which Fedora 13 lacks, so obviously it doesn't work. Is there other way to do it? I would like to use some scripts using Xrandr, but with TwinView setting it sees only one virtual screen stretched over two monitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a stupid question; if you make it create Xorg.conf, Fedora will use it. Yet I still don't know how to make it work well with Xrandr.